# Installing vscode, node, anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

My lecturer uploaded a youtube video explaining how to activate node and anaconda. I've installed node, anaconda (and vscode through the installation of the anaconda).

In the video, he says that we can check if the anaconda was installed properly by typing in the cmd 
`jupiter --version` and then the version should be presented on the screen. I get the message:

```
'jupiter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this so that I could see the version? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think he meant `jupyter` not `jupiter`. note the `y` instead of the `i`

Comment: yea, it was a typo mistake and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pointed by @sini you need to check `jupyter --version` instead `jupiter --version`

if jupyter not installed 
You need to install jupyter

`python3 -m pip install jupyter`

For windows get the [help](http://technivore.org/posts/2016/02/27/windows-jupyter-three-ways.html)

you can verify if juypter packaged installed by `pip  freeze` command

```
  jupyter==1.0.0
  jupyter-client==5.2.3
  jupyter-console==5.2.0
  jupyter-core==4.4.0 ....
```

Comment: doesn't `jupyter` come as part of anaconda? The OP said he installed anaconda? why use `pip` :) ?